# FastApi startup logic on redeployment of docker image

Tags: python, docker, continuous-integration, fastapi

I know that certain code that will only run on the first startup of FastApi can be placed in a startup method that will hendle such lifecycle events.
Lets say I have an FastAPI deployed in production as a docker image together with other services all tie together in a docker-compose and on startup I create the DB Tables with SQLAlchemy and maybe ad an admin user to the DB users table. Now I want to create a new deployment, so the new image is build and run. Will this re-execute this startup part?

How do I handle such new deployments safely, so that I do not overwrite existing things?

Comment: Use Alembic: https://alembic.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/ - and run `alembic upgrade head` as part of the startup script before starting your application. If the database is already updated, this will be a no-op; if any changes (migrations) have been added, they will run and bring your production database up to speed.